# Javascript - Convert Arabic Numerals to Chinese Characters

Tags: javascript, numbers, translation

I am trying to convert numbers (1, 2, 3...) to Chinese characters (一, 二/两，三...).  In Chinese, numbers are written [hundreds][100][tens][10][ones].  For example, 243 would be written as 2[100]4[10]3 or 三百四十三.  Is there a way to do this efficiently, or do I have to make a function that goes through each number and translates it by array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only two arrays, one for names of each digit and another for names of positions of digits in a number. Something like

```js
var digits = [ 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine' ]
var positions = [ 'ones', 'tens', 'hundreds' ];

toWords = num => String(243).split('').reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    console.log(parseInt(curr))
    acc += digits[parseInt(curr)] + positions.reverse()[index]
    return acc
  }, "")
console.log(toWords(243))
```

If you had the English words as Chinese characters, you'd get the desired result

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I know basically nothing about arrow functions, so could you please walk me through all of that!  Thanks

Comment: Basically we cast the Number into a String and then split that into an array of digits like `[ '2', '4', '3' ]` then take each digit and do a look up on the array of digit names. Cast the String '2' to an integer so that we can use it as array index in the look up such that 2 matches 'two'. The position of 2 in the number 243 is hundreds but the index of array reduce is 0 so we reverse the array of positions and retrieve element at index.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I finally understand those damn arrows! 

Answer (score 2):

I test all answers. I find no one is right. So I write a function by myself.Here is my code.

```js
function toChineseNumber(n) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(n) && n < 0) {
    throw Error('请输入自然数');
  }

  const digits = ['零', '一', '二', '三', '四', '五', '六', '七', '八', '九'];
  const positions = ['', '十', '百', '千', '万', '十万', '百万', '千万', '亿', '十亿', '百亿', '千亿'];
  const charArray = String(n).split('');
  let result = '';
  let prevIsZero = false;
  //处理0  deal zero
  for (let i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    const ch = charArray[i];
    if (ch !== '0' && !prevIsZero) {
      result += digits[parseInt(ch)] + positions[charArray.length - i - 1];
    } else if (ch === '0') {
      prevIsZero = true;
    } else if (ch !== '0' && prevIsZero) {
      result += '零' + digits[parseInt(ch)] + positions[charArray.length - i - 1];
    }
  }
  //处理十 deal ten
  if (n < 100) {
    result = result.replace('一十', '十');
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(toChineseNumber(123));
```

Comment: Results might be unexpected with leading zeros or large numbers. numberToChinese('00023') gives '零二十零三' numberToChinese('13111231')
'一千万三百万一十万一万一千二百三十一'

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [Number.prototype.toLocaleString Using locales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Using_locales)

```js
console.log(123456.789.toLocaleString('zh-u-nu-hanidec' )) // "一二三,四五六.七八九"

console.log(123456.789.toLocaleString('zh-u-nu-FullWide')) // "１２３,４５６.７８９"
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `var number = 11; console.log(number.toLocaleString('zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec'));` ---> outputs: "一一", it should output: "十一"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package: [`chinese-numbering`](https://github.com/EqualMa/chinese-numbering)

```js
const cn = window.ChineseNumbering;
console.log("11 => " + cn.numberToChinese(11));
console.log("11.5 => " + cn.numberToChinese(11.5));
console.log("-3.1415 => " + cn.numberToChinese(-3.1415));
console.log("繁体： 10000 => " + cn.numberToChinese(10000, 't'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chinese-numbering@1.x/bundle/iife.js"></script>
```